# What is this white spaces in stack and how to fix it

Tags: flutter, stack, overflow

Can someone explain why is there white spaces on top and bottom of this stack widget despite of no padding here?
[image]
I have a stack of progress bar and music details. Although I didn't add any padding but why is there the whitespaces in my widget? Is there anyway to fix this.
My code: mini_player.dart

```
import 'package:audio_video_progress_bar/audio_video_progress_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:webtoon/miniplayer/widgets/progress_bar.dart';

import '../riverpod/song_provider.dart';
import 'widgets/control_button.dart';

class MiniPlayer extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MiniPlayer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final audioPlayer = ref.watch(audioHandlerProvider);

    return GestureDetector(
      child: Align(
        alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
        child: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          height: 80,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset('assets/artwork.jpg',
                        width: 60, height: 60, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'The Weeknd',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Blinding Lights',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
                                fontSize: 13),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    Control(
                      audioPlayer: audioPlayer,
                      size: 20.0,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<PositionData>(
                  stream: PositionData.positionDataStream(audioPlayer),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final positionData = snapshot.data;

                    return ProgressBar(
                      barHeight: 5,
                      baseBarColor: Colors.black,
                      bufferedBarColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
                      progressBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      thumbColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      timeLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        fontSize: 0,
                      ),
                      progress: positionData?.position ?? Duration.zero,
                      buffered: positionData?.bufferedPosition ?? Duration.zero,
                      total: positionData?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
                      onSeek: audioPlayer.seek,
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/play'),
    );
  }
}
```

I have thought about changing the Container height from 80 to 60 to match the image height, the whitespaces did got away but instead i got overflow like this
[image]
How to fix this T_T, thanks very much.

Comment: Isn’t the top part of the progress bar widget? Do you want to put that on top of the others with a transparent background?

Comment: thanks, ur answer helps me get rid of the top ones. But now i realize the bottom whitespaces is caused by the column text widget, any idea on how to fix ? appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips on how to use the Widget Inspector to debug layout issues in Flutter:

**Step 1:**
Run your app directly in your IDE by clicking the "Run" button.

**Step 2:**
On the Run toolbar that appears, click the "Widget Inspector" icon.

[image]

**Step 3:**
Click the "Toggle select widget mode" on the top right of the inspector window.

[image]

**Step 4:**
Tap on the widget you want to inspect on your emulator or device.

[image]

**Step 5:**
The widget inspector will jump to the source code. Review the code and widget tree too look for any extra padding or margins.

[image]

**Extra Tip 1:**
You can also turn on the "Overlay guidelines" feature in the widget inspector window:

[image]

**Extra Tip 2:**
This will show an "X-Ray" view of your layout on your emulator.

[image]